# Call Download node app dependencies from another node application

Tags: node.js, npm

i have a command tool application developed using node. when pointed over a folder when i run a command it should install the node dependencies specified in the package.json file in the folder. is it possible to do like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
 exec = require('child_process').exec;
 exec(#your command starts here
```

But in general you should do googling before asking questions: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

also remember that user under which your tool is executed should have access rights to do so (e.g. root or destination folder owner)

PS: sorry for bad formatting and little text - typed from phone :)

Comment: no problem for the formatting. thank you very much for the help. i am new to node. that's why just couple of days before i started. thank you :)